# Is this a CSS bug on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, design

While I was reviewing some Questions and Answers I received notification that the post I was trying to improve was edited twice. Anyway, after dismissing the notification, it left a gap up there as shown in the screenshot, which left the header shifted as well.

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202789/edit-notification-display-issue - This was acknowledged as a returning bug, but I don't think anybody really did anything about it

Comment: should not this be reported here ? , and thanks for the link.

Comment: Absolutely (I didn't flag it or anything), just thought I would make a reference to the chain of events